# How to Get My Recursive Function to Return 0 in Python

Tags: python, recursion, printing, return

For my recursion assignment, the only built in function we are allowed to use is `len()` and 'print()'. So, not even `int()` is allowed to be used. The function I am supposed to make is supposed to break apart a number and print out each digit in the number.
So,

```
>>breakApart(757890)

7
5
7
8
9
0
```

This is what I have come up with so far,

```
def breakApart(number):
    c=0
    while number//10**c>=10:
        c+=1
    integer_part=((number-(number%10**c))//(10**c))
    if number//10**c==0:
        return
    elif number//10**c>0:
        print(integer_part)
        return breakApart(number%10**c)
```

This works for all numbers, except it will not print out 0s. I was thinking of writing something along the lines of,

```
if (number%10**c)>+10 and (number%10**c)//(10**(c-1))<1:
    print(0)
    return breakApart(number%10**c)
```

But if there are consecutive 0s, it will not print all of them. I guess I could use another counter like I did at the beginning, but if anyone could think of less convoluted ways for me to approach this, please let me know.

Comment: Is recursion a requirement?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga "For my recursion assignment..." - sounds like it.

Comment: @TomWyllie didn't read carefully enough :)

Comment: @sneakysnake I'm assuming using `print` is also allowed, given that you've used it?

Comment: What do you mean? It does print 0s.

Comment: What's the purpose of having len() if you can't use the str() function? Do you have to pass in an int? This would be really simple with recursion and a string

Comment: Yes, print is allowed. Will edit my question

Comment: You can use len if the input is a string, but you can't change the data type of int(4) to str(4) for example

Comment: And no, it cannot print 0s because the remainder from the mod ignores all of those 0s @coldspeed

Comment: @EastonBornemeier it's pretty simple with `int` and recursion as well.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I agree, but can't argue the fact that simply pulling characters off the sides of the string isn't a simple method if it was allowed

Answer (score 3):

Use recursion to your advantage here, making the `print` call come after your recursive call:

```
In [1]: def tell_digits(n):
   ...:     rest, first = n // 10, n % 10
   ...:     if rest:
   ...:         tell_digits(rest)
   ...:     print(first)
   ...:

In [2]: tell_digits(757890)
7
5
7
8
9
0
```

Note what happens if I put the `print` call *before* the recursive call:

```
In [3]: def tell_digits(n):
   ...:     rest, first = n // 10, n % 10
   ...:     print(first)
   ...:     if rest:
   ...:         tell_digits(rest)
   ...:

In [4]: tell_digits(757890)
0
9
8
7
5
7
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I don't want to steal this answer, however, since it deviates quite a bit from my code, but I'll use it as an example

Comment: Also, I'm a bit of a beginner, so I am trying to understand your code. What does "if rest" mean? If rest is what?

Comment: @sneakysnake `if rest:` checks if `rest` is [*falsey*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-in-python-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false). Also, see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing). In this case, it is the same as `if rest != 0:`

Answer (score 0):

If number can be a string:

```
def breakApart(number):
    if len(number) == 0:
        return
    else:
        print(number[0])
        breakApart(number[1:])
```

Or reverse it:

```
def breakApart(number):
    if len(number) == 0:
        return
    else:
        breakApart(number[:-1])
        print (number[-1])
```

Comment: No, we were given an example of the input being an integer type, not string type.

Answer (score 0):

Something to keep you up at night:

```
>>> def breakApart(number):
...     return number > 9 and breakApart(number // 10) or print(number % 10)
... 
>>> breakApart(757890)
7
5
7
8
9
0
>>>
```

Python 3 specific, of course.

Comment: This might take me a little while to understand, but thank you for another interesting answer :)